# An insect lays $k$ eggs with probability $p$, what is probability that $l$ of them hatch

Tags: probability

An insect lays $k$ eggs with probability $\frac{a^k}{k!}e^{-a}$, $a>0$. Newborn survive with probability $p$, independent of other. What is the probability that $l$ newborns survive?

Answer in my textbook is $\frac{(pa)^l}{l!}e^{-pa}$

Can someone explain why?

I thought about summing cases like if insect lays $l$ eggs then every newborn has to survive so the probability is $p^k$, if it lays $l+1$ eggs then one can die and so forth but there are infinitely many cases and I don't think it's a good idea to continue this way.

I saw some solutions using random variables and Poisson distribution but my textbook put this problem before these topics, it is in independednt events section.

Comment: Call $X$ number of newborns that survive and $N$ the number of eggs. Then $$P(X=l) = \sum_{n\geq l}P(X=l,N = n) $$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any way to simplify this expression of a probability further?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4597601/is-there-any-way-to-simplify-this-expression-of-a-probability-further)

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ be the number of newborns that survive and $N$ the number of eggs. Let $X_i$ be i.i.d Bernoulli $p$ r.v. Then
$$
X=\sum_{i=1}^NX_{i}.
$$
Here $X\mid N=n\sim \text{Bin(n,p)}$ while $N\sim\text{Poi(a)}$. Hence the moment generating function of $X$
$$
M_{X}(t) = Ee^{tX} = E(E(e^{tX}\mid N)))=\sum_{k=0}^\infty M_{X_{1}}(t)^nP(N=n) = G_{N}(M_{X_{1}}(t))\tag{0}
$$
where $G_{N}(t)=Et^X = \exp(a(t-1))$ is the probability generating function of $N$ and $M_{X_1}(t)=1-p+pe^t$ is the moment generating function of $X_1$.
So
$$
M_{X}(t) = \exp(a(pe^t-p)) =\exp(ap(e^t-1))
$$
which is the moment generating function for a Poisson random variable, specifically
$X\sim\text{Poi}(ap)$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative to @Sri-Amirthan Theivendran's excellent answer that avoids moment generating functions.

Let $X$ be the number of surviving newborns and $N$ the number of eggs. The question says that $P(N=k)=\frac{e^{-a}a^k}{k!}$ and $P(X=l | N=k)=\binom{k}{l}p^l (1-p)^{k-l}$ when $0\le k\le l$ and $0$ otherwise.

(that is, $N$ has a Poisson distribution with parameter $a$, and $(X|N=k)$ has a binomial distribution of parameters $k$ and $p$ but no knowledge on all this is needed)

We have

$$
P(X=l) 
= 
\sum_{k=l}^\infty P(X=l \text{ and }N=k) 
=
\sum_{k=l}^\infty P(X=l | N=k)P(N=k)
=
\sum_{k=l}^\infty \binom{k}{l}p^l (1-p)^{k-l}\frac{e^{-a}a^k}{k!}
$$

so, using $\binom{k}{l}=\frac{k!}{(k-l)!l!}$, we get

$$
P(X=l) 
= 
\frac{e^{-a}p^l}{l!}\sum_{k=l}^\infty \frac{a^k(1-p)^{k-l}}{(k-l)!}
= 
\frac{e^{-a}p^l}{l!}\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{a^{l+j}(1-p)^{j}}{j!}
= 
\frac{e^{-a}p^la^l}{l!}\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{(a(1-p))^{j}}{j!}
$$

Since $e^x=\sum_{j=0}^\infty\frac{x^j}{j!}$ for every real number $x$, we obtain

$$
P(X=l) 
= 
\frac{e^{-a}p^la^l}{l!}e^{a(1-p)} = \frac{(al)^l}{l!}e^{-pa}
$$